# What is the unit of x-axis of a sound signal?

Tags: speech-processing

I'm confused about the unit of x-axis.

The below signal has a duration of 3 second and sampling frequency 44100. So should i write Time(s) for the unit of x-axis.

However, in the graph, it shows the number of samples i.e 44100 * 3 = 132300.

[image]

Comment: SE.DSP wishes you a happy new year 2017, with a kind reminder that your question and its answers may require some action (update, votes, acceptance, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The below signal has a duration of 3 second and sampling frequency 44100. So should i write Time(s) for the unit of x-axis.

No. In your graph, the X axis seems to be simply the sample number. I mean, it's a bit strange to ask us, considering *you* generated the graph, but if you benefit from having it spelled out:

In DSP, signals are represented by a sequence of samples. And if you plot these samples, there's no inherent "units" on the X axis. Your signal has been reduced to a sequence of digital numbers, and the fact that there was a sampling rate that implies some period of time between each sample is simply not there in DSP.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was strange to me to define the unit as sample so i needed to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to have proper axis labels, on both the $x$ and $y$-axis. And a legend or a title. 
Digital signal processing usually deals with regularly sampled data, in which the actual sampling frequency "almost" vanishes: samples are separated by a sort of unitless length $1$ interval. So, many low-level processing use a "**sample index**" $x$-axis. I prefer *sample index* to *sample number*.

However, when it comes to event location, comparison of frames of different length, data with different sampling rates, a label with  a multiple of seconds can be preferred.